# Free socket port. Delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, port

How can I find a free socket port, using Delphi?
As I know , there is a function bind() - but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Don't the clients need to know the port number to connect? Personally I choose one that is not used from this list: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml

Answer (score 1):

You make attempts to `bind` until you find a free one. That is, straightforwardly - you start from certain value and increment until `bind` succeeds.

Comment: If you specify port 0 instead when calling `bind()`, it picks a free port automatically for you, and then you can use `getsockname()` to find out which port it choise.  No need to hunt for ports manually (unless you want to limit the port range), which has an inherant race condition to it.

Comment: This is true, thanks for correction. It is the best way if you don't care for port number. If you have preferences, such as preferred port range, you might still need to hunt.